# list indices must be integers or slices not tuple

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to reorganize my data to a specific format, and found stuck at the error message.

I'm looking into a 16-columned csv file and I want to merge column 1-5 into a single column while also appending 10th column right next to it, while discarding the rest of the columns.

I have about 30 of such csv files and would like to process all of them into a single comprehensive list. File names are iterative yet they can be defined by the number in the middle. Ptrain0dataset, Ptrain50dataset, Ptrain100dataset ...

Here's the code I'm juggling with:

```
clist=[]
for i in range(0,17):
    a=i*50
    with open('Ptrain' + str(a) + 'dataset,csv', 'r') as f:
        temp=f.readlines()
        temp2=[]
        for i in temp:
            j=i.replace('""', '')
            temp2.append(j.split(','))
        for j in temp2:
                clist[str(a), j[0:5], j[9]]
        f.close()
```

stacktrace:

```
 File "<ipython-input-23-e7da8e2724f8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('pfiles')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "pfiles/aa.py", line 35, in <module>
    clist[str(a), j[0:5], j[9]]
```

I can't seem to figure out whats the mistake in here.

Comment: Please share the last few relevant lines of your stack-trace too

Comment: What do you expect `clist[str(a), j[0:5], j[9]]` to do?

Comment: @user2357112 I wanna trace where each columns derived from (among 30+ csv. files). Since the files are identified with their assigned numbers (50 intervals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in this line:

```
clist[str(a), j[0:5], j[9]]
```

You are indexing a `list` by a tuple, not an integer.

Comment: This may sound stupid but i thought tuples are created with (,) instead of []?

Comment: @Kimmy, tuples are created with a comma, for example: `my_tuple = 4,5`, in your case: `str(a), j[0:5], j[9]` is a tuple.